# Why is php strtotime() not working on a date?

Tags: php, strtotime

This is the code I have used. Why can't it understand this date?

```
strtotime('FRI OCT 14TH 2016'); //returns Thursday 01 01 1970
```

Comment: Because thats not a supported format, [Date Formats](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: You can use `strtotime(strtolower('FRI OCT 14TH 2016'))`

Comment: strtolower fixed it!. - I didn't see anything in the manual that said use lowercase strings only.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('FRI OCT 14 2016'));   // remove TH from 14TH
```

it will return

> 14-10-2016

Comment: Nope. It will return `31-12-1969`, unless you use `strtolower()` with it.

Comment: Rax 14-10-2016 is returned after running the code on php online environment ie. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com

Comment: And please consider my comment i.e. // remove TH from 14TH

Comment: I have found you can either lowercase the (TH) or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

As [Neat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1897253/neat) mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995013/why-is-php-strtotime-not-working-on-a-date?rq=1#comment67267896_39995013):

> Because thats not a supported format, [Date Formats](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

Looking at the PHP documentation for [Date Formats](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php), the first row in the table describes the suffixes supported on dates (see the screenshot below). Notice that the letters are all lower-case.

[image: Date format for suffixes].

Thus as was mentioned in comments, use lower-case letters for the suffixes.

```
strtotime('FRI OCT 14th 2016');
```

See a demonstration of this change in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/zXXzCkfH23otqlBu).